# Vue Bootstrap - I need to click twice to open the next tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this Vue JS tabs:

```
<b-tabs v-model="tabIndex">
    <b-tab title="Settings">
        <validation-observer ref="validateSetting" tag="form">
            my htmlform......
            <b-button variant="primary" type="submit" @click.prevent="validateSetting"> Next </b-button>
        </validation-observer>
    </b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Edit Mapping" :disabled="mapingDisabled">
        <validation-observer ref="validateEditMapping" tag="form">
            my htmlform......
            <b-button variant="primary" type="submit" @click.prevent="validateEditMapping"> Next Steps </b-button>
        </validation-observer>
    </b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Safety" :disabled="safetyDisable">
        <b-button variant="primary" type="submit" @click.prevent="submitXml" > Submit </b-button>
    </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

Each tab contain HTML form which is validating using `validation-observer` means user can't go to next tab until the current tab validation is done.

Here on the second and third I have disabled it using `:disabled="mapingDisabled"` and `:disabled="safetyDisable"`.

Now, If I click on the **button** of the first tab it's not immediately go to the second tab ! **I have to click again to go to the second and so one...** why?

**Here is what I am using on the script part:**

**On the data property I have this 2 property:**

```
mapingDisabled: true,
safetyDisable: true,
tabIndex: 1,
```

**and the methods:**

```
validateSetting() {
    this.$refs.validateSetting.validate().then((success) => {                       
        if (success) {
            this.mapingDisabled = false;
            this.tabIndex++;
            let _this = this;
            if (this.countHTTP == 0) {
                this.callHttp();
                this.countHTTP++;
            }
        }
    });
},
callHttp() {
    let importData = {
        token: this.mappingData.token,
        xml_file_url: this.mappingData.xml_file_url,
        name: this.mappingData.mapping_name,
        encoding : this.mappingData.encoding,
    };
    http.post("projects/import/", importData)
        .then((response) => {
            let res = response.data;
            let _this = this;

            if (res.status !== 1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    _this.callHttp();
                    this.loadDone = true;
                }, 5000);
            } else if (res.status === 1) {
                this.loadDone = false;
                this.mappingData.id_feed = res.id_feed;
                res.field_names.forEach(function (item, index) {
                    _this.mappingData.projectFieldOptions.push({
                        value: item,
                        text: item,
                        custom: false,
                    });
                });
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
},
validateEditMapping() {
    this.$refs.validateEditMapping.validate().then((success) => {
        if (success) {
            this.tabIndex++;
            this.safetyDisable = false;
        }
    });
},
submitXml() {
    http.post("projects/import/mapping/", this.mappingData)
        .then((response) => {
            for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.mappingData)) {
                delete this.mappingData[prop];
            }
            this.$bvModal.hide("import-xml-modal");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I think so "this.tabIndex++;" should be "this.tabIndex += 1;".But I haven't tested it,You can try it.

Comment: Okay. Let me try with this.

Comment: NO, Its not woriing. I have to click twice